# how to setting BPEL assign variable's

Tags: wsdl, bpel

there's my bpel process picture

http://imageshack.com/a/img661/5192/tuwh8i.jpg

first Invoke Partner link parameters are

```
<element minOccurs="0" name="currDateE" type="xs:dateTime"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="currDateS" type="xs:dateTime"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="disc_cond_id" type="xs:int"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="disc_condition" type="xs:string"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="disc_conditions" type="xs:string"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="disc_end_date" type="xs:dateTime"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="disc_end_time" type="xs:dateTime"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="disc_logic" type="xs:string"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="disc_name" type="xs:string"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="disc_service_id" type="xs:int"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="disc_start_date" type="xs:dateTime"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="disc_start_time" type="xs:dateTime"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="disc_type_id" type="xs:int"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="discount_value" type="xs:int"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="insert_org_id" type="xs:int"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="isic_code" type="xs:string"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="lang_id" type="xs:string"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="org_id" type="xs:long"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="serv_disc_id" type="xs:int"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="service_id" type="xs:int"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="tm_desc" type="xs:string"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="tm_id" type="xs:int"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="tm_name" type="xs:string"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="tm_pid" type="xs:int"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="tm_type" type="xs:int"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="values_type" type="xs:int"/>
```

next Invoke (Invoke1) parameters are

```
<element minOccurs="0" name="c_price" type="xs:decimal"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="customer_id" type="xs:long"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="dcopl_id" type="xs:int"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="discount_count" type="xs:int"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="discount_flag" type="xs:int"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="mt_id" type="xs:int"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="n_price" type="xs:decimal"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="order_id" type="xs:int"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="orderpay_id" type="xs:int"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="ot_name" type="xs:string"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="pay_flag" type="xs:int"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="pay_price" type="xs:decimal"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="pay_type" type="xs:int"/>
   <element minOccurs="0" name="payment_org_id" type="xs:long"/>
```

i just want first invoke disc_cond_id setting to next invoke orderpay_id